# How to persist a process in python

Tags: python, pytorch

I have the following Pytorch code, what the code does is:

1. Loads Pytorch object detection model into RAM using `net=CRAFT()`
2. using `net.eval()` it runs inference
3. Using the for loop I am supplying images to run inference on one by one

code:

```
def copyStateDict(state_dict):
    if list(state_dict.keys())[0].startswith("module"):
        start_idx = 1
    else:
        start_idx = 0
    new_state_dict = OrderedDict()
    for k, v in state_dict.items():
        name = ".".join(k.split(".")[start_idx:])
        new_state_dict[name] = v
    return new_state_dict


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # load net
    net = CRAFT()     # initialize

    print('Loading weights from checkpoint (' + args.trained_model + ')')
    if args.cuda:
        net.load_state_dict(copyStateDict(torch.load(args.trained_model)))
    else:
        net.load_state_dict(copyStateDict(torch.load(args.trained_model, map_location='cpu')))

    if args.cuda:
        net = net.cuda()
        net = torch.nn.DataParallel(net)
        cudnn.benchmark = False

    net.eval()

    t = time.time()

    # load data
    for k, image_path in enumerate(image_list):
        print("Test image {:d}/{:d}: {:s}".format(k+1, len(image_list), image_path), end='\r')
        image = imgproc.loadImage(image_path)

        bboxes, polys, score_text = test_net(net, image, args.text_threshold, args.link_threshold, args.low_text, args.cuda, args.poly)

        # save score text
        #filename, file_ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(image_path))
        #mask_file = result_folder + "/res_" + filename + '_mask.jpg'
        #cv2.imwrite(mask_file, score_text)

        file_utils.saveResult(image_path, image[:,:,::-1], polys, dirname=result_folder)

    print("elapsed time : {}s".format(time.time() - t))
```

There is a caveat in this code, especially the fact that it occupies `1.8 GB` of RAM each time I do step **1** and **2**. The actual inference on images takes much lesser RAM (40mb per image), but the majority of my memory consumption comes from loading the `ML` model into RAM. Is there a way in which I can keep loaded this model into RAM on a server and then just perform inferences on the images?

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much described a web server. You can create a trivial API around this with something like [flask](https://palletsprojects.com/p/flask/) which would load the model at startup and receive either images or paths in the web request, then return a response. Run it with `uwsgi` or something similar to have more than one worker available at a time (just make sure the model is initialised once, not per-worker).

Or you could go more fancy and use one of the many RPC libraries to create a similar kind of local server.

Comment: Hi @viraptor please explain why the model should be initialized once and not per worker - this may be related to an issue I am running into.

Comment: @Luther Because if you do it per-worker, you'll use N*1.8GB memory where N is your number of workers. If the model doesn't change during inference you can (probably) use gc.freeze and the you'll have only one copy instead.